# Docker Compose CLI Flags

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am not sure how to run the `docker-compose` equivalent of the following...

```
docker run -d -p 8080:9000 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock portainer/portainer --logo "https://www.docker.com/sites/all/themes/docker/assets/images/brand-full.svg"`
```

So far, I have the following, which I know works...

```
ui:   
   image: portainer/portainer
   container_name: ui
   restart: always
   volumes:
     - '/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock'
   expose:
     - 9000
   ports:
     - 8080:9000
```

Specifically, I can't figure out how the `--logo` flag translates to compose.

Comment: Have you seen any documentation for the --logo flag? Never seen it before.

Comment: Documentation for the `--logo` flag is available here: https://portainer.readthedocs.io/en/stable/configuration.html#use-your-own-logo

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`docker run`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/) does not mention any `--logo` parameter [in its reference man page](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/).

That means it could *maybe* represent a parameter pass to the default CMD of the [container `portainer/portainer`](https://github.com/portainer/portainer) being run.
That seems to be the case in [issue 399](https://github.com/portainer/portainer/issues/399#issuecomment-268140949):

> You can use the CLI flags in the command field of your docker-compose file:

```
  ui:
    image: portainer/portainer
    command: portainer --logo http://mylogo.com -l owner=acme --templates http://mytemplates.com
    container_name: ui
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - '/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock'
```

[Tony](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1127536/tony) points out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41234010/docker-compose-cli-flags/41235615?noredirect=1#comment69823341_41235615) to a [`docker-compose` example](https://github.com/portainer/portainer-compose)

Comment: It is indeed a portainer flag and not a Docker flag, good answer here. Also we have an example of docker-compose file available at https://github.com/portainer/portainer-compose

Comment: @Tony Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.